# Permission forbidden on localhost with apache2

Tags: 13.04, server, permissions, apache2

I tried to add another folder to apache and I get the following error when trying to acces `testing/index.html`.

The idea is that I would like to have for every customer a folder like `/home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/[PROJECT NAME]/CustomerProjects/website/dist`.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at testing Port 80

Here are the steps that I followed:

**Step1:**

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist
```

**Step2:**

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist

sudo chmod -R 775 /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist
```

**Step3:**

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

**Step4:**

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

**Step5:**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache/sites-available/default /etc/apache/sites-available/testing
```

I edited the file `/etc/apache/sites-available/testing` so it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName testing
    DocumentRoot /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/neagoe/Work/InterWebs/Projects/testing/CustomerProjects/website/dist/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step6:**

I edited hosts ("/etc/hosts") so it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.0.1       testing


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**Step7:**

```
sudo a2ensite testing
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I searched for about 2 hours on the internet but I can't figure out what went wrong.
All the pages that I found following the same steps as described above.

I know there are similar questions here on AskUbuntu, but the answer is to change permision to the directory which I did on **Step2**.

I am sorry if this is really a duplicate but I could't find the right answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , I edit the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`file and add

```
<Directory /var/www/ >
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and reset the apache2

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

work for me .